# Is there a way to compute how much memory a Metal texture is using before allocation?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

For memory management purpose I need to know how much memory is needed for Metal textures.
I know I need to page align the buffer to estimate the size, but for some reason, my estimation is incorrect.

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
import Darwin
import Metal
import MetalKit
import UIKit

func estimate(width: Int, height: Int) -> Int {
    let pageSize = Int(getpagesize())
    let unalignedSize = width * height * 4 // let's assume 32bits ARGB texture

    return ((unalignedSize + pageSize - 1) / pageSize) * pageSize
}

func actually(width: Int, height: Int) -> Int {
    let l = MTKTextureLoader(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
    let options : [MTKTextureLoader.Option : NSObject] = [
        MTKTextureLoader.Option.allocateMipmaps : NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
        MTKTextureLoader.Option.generateMipmaps : NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
        MTKTextureLoader.Option.textureUsage    : NSNumber(value: MTLTextureUsage.shaderRead.rawValue),
        MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB            : NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false)
    ]
    let t = try! l.newTexture(cgImage: generateMonochromeImage(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)), options: options)

    return t.allocatedSize
}

func generateMonochromeImage(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> CGImage {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 1.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image.cgImage!
}



estimate(width: 414, height: 512) //-> 851968
actually(width: 414, height: 512) //-> 917504
estimate(width: 363, height: 512) //-> 753664
actually(width: 363, height: 512) //-> 786432
```

As you can see estimations are off...

**Is there a way to predict/compute how much a MTLTexture will allocate?**

Comment: Due to device-specific considerations I suspect the answer is 'no'. For example, some devices will tile the image in memory, while others will compress it or have some kind of a stride to make the pixels easier for the hardware to address. If you ran your test on other devices (Mac GPUs or even other iOS GPU generations), you might see different actual figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one issue is the row byte alignment (a.k.a. `bytesPerRow`). For the hardware, accessing rows that are aligned to certain powers of two is more efficient. So, that's how data is stored internally.

From your numbers, it seems the texture is using 256 bytes per row. So a row that's 414 pixels wide with 4 bytes per pixel would require 1656 bytes. But that's not a multiple of 256. So, the rows will be padded out to the next multiple of 256, which is 1792. That times 512 rows is 917504.

But, as Idoogy mentions in a comment, that's not predictable across all hardware.

Comment: I ran some tests, and sizes seem hard to predict...
As suggested by @Idoogy results depend on the platform. On A12X & A13 you need to add one page for these examples.
The suggested 256 bytes aligned row heuristic does not work for every dimensions.
One could probably test every single permutation for every device (only 2^28), but it does not seems practical to exploit in a lut.
Also it does not seems related to MTLDevice.minimumLinearTextureAlignment(for:) which returns 64 on every devices I tested.
So I guess I'll have to accommodate inaccurate estimations...